# How to create rich text box, that can replace text with Angular Components

Tags: angular, typescript, rich-text-editor, angular-dynamic-components

I want to create content editor, similar to facebook "create post" textbox, that is able to replace some tokens (e.g words starting with @ or #) with some angular components.

E.g.

`Hello, @John`, would be replaced by `Hello, <app-username user="John"></app-username>`

Comment: a good place to start would be angular's docs for [dynamic component loading](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)

Comment: Take a look at [Tagify](https://yaireo.github.io/tagify/#section-extra-properties). I think it is what you are looking for.